# Create Ribbon button in Outlook 2016 to forward e-mail

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am new to C# but not coding.

I'm after a way to create an button in Home ribbon in Outlook 2016 to forward selected e-mail to a specific e-mail address.

I have Visual Studio installed and have created a very basic button and ribbon. So far the code just creates a new email, I would like to it when a user selects an email and clicks the button it forwards the email to a specific email address.

```
try
        {
            Outlook._Application _Application = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mail.To = "<Email address>";
            mail.Subject = "Test e-mail from Addin";
            mail.Body = "This is a test email";
            mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
            ((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Send();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Well, the first thing you have to do is go through the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019. This is not a tutorials site

Comment: Well ok thanks.  That link is not specific to creating buttons and using email controls. I will keep looking.

Comment: You certainly didn't read at all the link I provided, it shows how to create a tab with a button on it.

Comment: I did, I know how to create a ribbon and a button. My question is how to get a selected email forwarded to a specific email address using a button.

Comment: Maybe you also want this then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813402/c-sharp-outlook-add-in-get-selected-emails

Comment: Have you figured out the solution? It would help if you could update this question with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Applicatiobn.ActiveExplorer.Selection` to retrieve the currently selected message(s), then call `MailItem.Forward` - it will return a brand new `MailItem` object with the appropriately formatted body and attachments. Set the recipients (`Mailtem.To` or `MailItem.Recipients.Add`) and call `MailItem.Send`.